# The reason I'm writing this email is to

Tags: style, redundancy

I saw the following sentence at the start of an e-mail. While it is grammatical, I'd like know if it is natural.

> Dear Mr. Smith:
>
> The reason I'm writing this e-mail is to inform you of a change to our August schedule.

Comment: I've seen similar uses, and it does not strike me as unnatural.

Comment: At the start of an email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *formal* letter, you would normally begin this way:

> I write to inform you of a change to our August schedule.

An email is really no different - although many people adopt a more *informal* approach to sending emails, you have begun with the proper address "*Dear Mr Smith*", so it seems that you should follow the conventions of a letter.

In *informal* correspondence people tend to "get to the point". "The reason I am writing this email" is pretty superfluous - of course it's an email, it came into my inbox.

Informally, you are more likely to see:

> Just letting you know about a change to our August schedule.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there anything wrong with "I am writing to inform you of a change to our August schedule," using the present progressive instead of the simple present?

Comment: @Apollyon that's fine too, and a good compromise!